# Why is mapping <c-e> to expand emmet-vim abbreviation not working?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

I have the following in my `_vimrc` and `_gvimrc` (I'm using Windows 10):

```
set tabstop=4
set sts=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set number    
let g:emmet_html5 = 1
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key = '<c-e>'
```

When I edit an HTML file with Vim, I want to be able to expand an abbreviation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

But, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, it doesn't expand. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (the default mapping), it does expand.

Why is `let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key = '<c-e>'` not taking effect?

No mapping found for `map <c-e>`.
[image]

I am sure that mapping was written into `_vimrc` and `_gvimrc`.

Display all `scriptname`:
[image]

My installation:

- Download gvim8.2.exe from [gvim.exe](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim82.exe) and double click to install on `d:` partition.
- Download emmet-vim-master from  [emmet-vim-master](https://codeload.github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/zip/master) and extract all files in it.

  - copy all files and directory in  `emmet-vim-master/autoload/` into `d:\Vim\vim8.2\autoload\`.
  - copy file in `emmet-vim-master/plugin/` into `d:\Vim\vim8.2\plugin\`.

Then rewrite the _vimrc file.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo that doesn't do what you probably think it does. What you've effectively done is run `:h :g` using `:` as the delimiter and `user_emmet_expandabbr_key` as the pattern, with `verbose` set to 1. @showkey, what is the output of `:map <c-e>`?

Comment: @JakeGrossman you are totally right.... it just made sense since I have tried it in my vimrc... *facepalm* thx

Comment: Could you post the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: Also, can you edit your post to describe how you've installed the `emmet-vim` plugin?

Answer (score 0):

My vim installed in `d:\Vim` ,but there is a `_vimrc` in `c:`,delete  `_vimrc` in `c:` ,issue solved.